# Hyperledger Fabric: "./network.sh deployCC" error

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I download Hyper-ledger Fabric using docker

when I run the command `./network.sh deployCC`
I got this error

````
Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'basic.tar.gz': open basic.tar.gz: no such file or directory
Chaincode packaging has failed
Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'basic.tar.gz': open basic.tar.gz: no such file or directory
Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
Using organization 1
+ peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled --output json
+ grep '^$'
+ jq -r 'try (.installed_chaincodes[].package_id)'
+ test 1 -ne 0
+ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
+ res=1```
Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'basic.tar.gz': open basic.tar.gz: no such file or directory
Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed
Deploying chaincode failed

what is the issue and how can I fix it?


what and how can I fix it?
````

Answer (score 0):

**run the complete command**

> ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go

**you can also use other lang**

> asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-javascript -ccl javascript
> or
> asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-java -ccl java